# Bitmap .clone gets error "OBJECT IS CURRENTLY IN USE ELSEWHERE"

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, bitmap

I'm getting this error during event with camera frame Bitmap from USB camera when I try to clone the Bitmap to change its format from 32bpp to 24bpp, in order to match input requirement of later comparison method.

Using Visual Studio 2017 Pro C# on Windows 10.

Initialize Bitmap objects...

```
namespace ACCORD_WindowsFormsApp9
{
    public partial class Control_Panel : Form
                    static Bitmap camera_snapshot_Bitmap = null;
                    static Bitmap camera_frame_Bitmap = null;
                    static Bitmap latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap = null;
                    static Bitmap latest_frame_clone_Bitmap = null;
                    static Bitmap reference_snapshot_Bitmap = null, reference_cropped_Bitmap = null;
                    static Bitmap target_snapshot_Bitmap = null, target_cropped_Bitmap = null;
            static int PictureBox_live_camera_changes = 0;


. . .

        // CONSTRUCTOR:
        public Control_Panel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        // Automatically start inputing each frame from camera:
            var videoDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            // Select physical USB camera:
                videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice( videoDevices[0].MonikerString, pixelFormat_for_ExhaustiveTemplateMatching);


        // Select event handlers:
            videoSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(Event_camera_frame);
            PictureBox_live_camera.Paint +=     Event_draws_crop_rectangle;

        // Start slurpin up them camera frames:
            videoSource.Start();

       }
```

Event fires with latest frame from USB camera..............

```
private  void Event_camera_frame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs camera_frame_event)
{

    // Select latest frame from camera:   
        if( camera_snapshot_Bitmap != null )
        {
            camera_snapshot_Bitmap.Dispose();
        }
        Bitmap  camera_frame_Bitmap =  camera_frame_event.Frame;                       // copy pointer

        camera_snapshot_Bitmap = new Bitmap( rotation_filter.Apply(   camera_frame_Bitmap ));           

        if(  latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap != null )
        {   
             latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap.Dispose();
        }
        latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap = new Bitmap(    camera_snapshot_Bitmap );           // copy frame bitmap data to buffer for later image snapshotting
        latest_frame_clone_Bitmap = latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap.Width, latest_frame_buffer_Bitmap.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb );

        set_display_rectangle();        //   PictureBox_latest_frame  ==>  display_rectangle X, Y, Width, Height
    update_target_view();
}




void update_target_view()
{
        if( PictureBox_live_camera_changes == 0 )       return;

        PictureBox_live_camera.Image = latest_frame_clone_Bitmap;
        PictureBox_live_camera.BackgroundImage = latest_frame_clone_Bitmap;
            PictureBox_live_camera_changes = 1;

 }

    void Event_draws_crop_rectangle(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle( crop_pen, display_rectangle );                     /////////////   DRAW CROP RECTANGLE   /////////////
    }
    private void set_display_rectangle( )
    {
        int width, height;
            width = PictureBox_live_camera.Width;
            height = PictureBox_live_camera.Height;

        // Set crop factor as a function of max_wheel_clicks:
            double crop_factor_X =  Convert.ToDouble( mouse_wheel_clicksX ) /   max_wheel_clicksX;     // min 0 .. 1.0 max
            double crop_factor_Y =  Convert.ToDouble( mouse_wheel_clicksY ) /   max_wheel_clicksY;     // min 0 .. 1.0 max

        // Adjust crop rectangle to match mouse wheel:
            // Adjust height & width of crop rectangle by the crop factor:
                display_width_pixels  = Convert.ToInt32( width  * crop_factor_X  - crop_pen_size_pixels * 2);
                if( display_width_pixels < 5 )      display_width_pixels = 5;
                display_height_pixels = Convert.ToInt32( height * crop_factor_Y  - crop_pen_size_pixels * 2 ) ;
                if( display_height_pixels < 5 )     display_height_pixels = 5;

            // Adjust crop rectangle upper left x & y as a function of crop rectangle that will be centered within target image:
                display_x_pixels =  Convert.ToInt32( width  / 2.0 -  display_width_pixels / 2.0  + crop_shift_pixelX );
                display_y_pixels =  Convert.ToInt32( height / 2.0 -  display_height_pixels / 2.0 + crop_shift_pixelY );

            display_rectangle.Width =    display_width_pixels;
            display_rectangle.Height =   display_height_pixels;
            display_rectangle.X  =   display_x_pixels;
            display_rectangle.Y =    display_y_pixels;
    }
```

Comment: You're subscribing the `Paint` event of `PictureBox_live_camera` each time a new frame is processed: `PictureBox_live_camera.Paint += Event_draws_crop_rectangle`. For every subscription, you have a new event. After a little while those events overlap with the frame update event handler (`Event_camera_frame`) and anything can happen. You should instead move `PictureBox_live_camera.Paint += Event_draws_crop_rectangle` to the class constructor and, in its place, `Invalidate()` your PictureBox. Imo, you also shouldn't use static Bitmaps. Maybe, make a class container for those.

Comment: Thanks, Jimi.  I fixed that.  But I'm still getting 'Object is currently in use elsewhere'.

Comment: The NewFrame event is raised on a worker thread.  But the Paint event is raised on the UI thread.  You cannot use Clone(), you must make a deep copy.  Use the new Bitmap(Image) constructor.  You also cannot safely assign the PictureBox.Image property in the worker thread, you must use its BeginInvoke() method to ensure the assignment occurs on the UI thread.

Comment: Besides what Hans said, try making a copy of the Bitmap returned by the `NewFrame` Handler, changing `Bitmap camera_frame_Bitmap =  camera_frame_event.Frame;`  to  `Bitmap camera_frame_Bitmap =  new Bitmap(camera_frame_event.Frame);`. Also, see if you can safely Clone() it.